# How to exit a for /f loop in a batch ?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a question about a batch file that I am writing.

How can I define my "for /f" loop to execute only one part of my script and not the whole script ?

In the script below, I would like

I precise that I need to use a "call" method (because of another issue with backlash).

Thank you for your help :)

```
    @echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  WMIC LOGICALDISK where drivetype=3 get caption>%~n0.tmp
  for /f "tokens=1-3 skip=1" %%a in ('type "%~n0.tmp"') do call :displayinfo %%a
del "%~n0.tmp"
goto :eof

:displayinfo
set drive=%1
echo Le drive est %drive%
echo lancement du DIR
REM call dir /A HS /s /b %drive%\ >> d:\Dir_ALL.txt
echo Fin du DIR

:step2
echo this is the step2, to be executed when the for /F loop is over.
echo blablalblablalballbabal

:step_End
echo Ths is the end
@pause
```

Comment: usual way is to use `goto :label` which breaks the `for` context , but what loop you want to exit of.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I want to my script to list every drives with WMIC, then execute the :displayinfo label. So I want it to execute a DIR /A HS ... on each drive that was found. Then when this loop is over, I want to go to "step2", etc.. (so not in the loop anymore).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make two changes.

1. Change the `goto :eof` two lines below your `for` line to `goto :step2`.
2. Add `goto :EOF` as the last line of your `:displayinfo` method. This will cause the method to return to the `for` loop.

It should look like this.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
WMIC LOGICALDISK where drivetype=3 get caption>%~n0.tmp
for /f "tokens=1-3 skip=1" %%a in ('type "%~n0.tmp"') do call :displayinfo %%a
del "%~n0.tmp"
goto :step2

:displayinfo
set drive=%1
echo Le drive est %drive%
echo lancement du DIR
REM call dir /A HS /s /b %drive%\ >> d:\Dir_ALL.txt
echo Fin du DIR
goto :EOF

:step2
echo this is the step2, to be executed when the for /F loop is over.
echo blablalblablalballbabal

:step_End
echo Ths is the end
@pause
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I wasnt understanding correctly the means of the "EOF".